# Capture camera + mic and encode to h264/aac on macOS

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, h.264, capture, aac

I'm having trouble capturing and encoding audio+video on-the-fly on macOS.

I tried two options:

1. ffmpeg

   ```
   ffmpeg -threads 0 -f avfoundation -s 1920x1080 -framerate 25 -I 0:0 -async 441 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 22 -c:a libfdk_aac -aq 95 -y
   ```
2. gstreamer

   ```
   gst-launch-1.0 -ve avfvideosrc device-index=0 ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=25/1 ! vtenc_h264 ! queue ! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=out.mp4  osxaudiosrc device=0 ! audio/x-raw ! faac midside=false ! queue ! mux.
   ```

The ffmpeg option works, but only for lower resolutions. With higher resolutions, the Mac mini (2018 gen) can't do the heavy lifting. I think because I installed ffmpeg with brew, so it wasn't compiled on my machine, meaning it doesn't use the h264 hardware encoder in the Mac?

The gstreamer option works as well, but there's a slight audio/video sync issue (audio is 100ms ahead of the video). I can't seem to add delay to the GStreamer queue (it ignores it):

```
queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 min-threshold-time=100000000
```

Anyone who has any experience with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That change in the queues effects internal flow only. It has no impact on timestamps on the buffers traveling through the pipeline. The timestamps define how the sync between audio and video is.

Try to use the `identity` element on either the video or audio path and set some timestamp offset via the `ts-offset` property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try this. I was wondering, though, if there's a *good* way to achieve A/V sync? I'm 100% sure the source is in sync (SDI -> USB3 capture card), I've also verified this by capturing a clip in RAW using Quicktime Player. So maybe I'm missing something in my pipelines to sync them together?

Comment: They should be in sync by default. But since audio and video sources use completely different APIs in your case they may have a different understanding about the initial device's latency.

Comment: So this means the initial latency is a constant value and the best way to fix this would be to use the ts-offset you proposed? Or is there another way to sync them? Or is there a better way/tool to achieve my goal (capture audio + video from capture card in h264/aac on-the-fly)?

Comment: I tried adding the identity element, but it doesn't seem to delay the audio. I tried two seconds delay in audio, to make sure: gst-launch-1.0 -ve avfvideosrc device-index=0 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! vtenc_h264 ! queue  ! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=out.mp4  osxaudiosrc device=0 ! audio/x-raw ! faac midside=false ! identity ts-offset=2000000000 ! queue ! mux.

Comment: Hm maybe my memory tricked me here.. I though this would work. Normally I would add a pad probe in my application and modify timestamps manually. But this requires a real application and cannot be done via gst-launch alone. Alternatively you may want to try `do-timestamp=true` for one or both of your source elements. Then the sample will get time stamps when the samples are being processed. So that will be a real live scenario. You may still be affected if the data does have a latency on one of the paths though.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. As you can probably tell, I'm quite new to GStreamer (I'm used to using ffmpeg for stuff like this, but GStreamer seems to be the better alternative here). Would you mind sharing a small demo application to achieve this?

Comment: I recommend reading the docs really. It may appear a lot at first, but there is no real shortcut if you want to work with it. For probes: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/probes.html . But starting here https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/index.html isn't bad either.

Comment: As it turns out, it does work on a Macbook of a friend of mine. It doesn't on mine though. The only difference we found is that he's on High Sierra, and I'm on Mojave. Maybe there's some bugs related to the latest macOS?